# How to add border color in Mat Input Field in Angular

Tags: angular

Is there any way by which we can add border color in mat input field in Angular , by default it comes with no border and when we hover over it it gets a border black .

Can we change the default behaviour to black border ? I am unable to do that by any css .

I used this -

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Add `::ng-deep` and it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write this css at the end of **style.css** file

if you have added this css on **Component.css** then it will not work

if it still not works then try with **!important**

hope it will usefull for all

**Reason**

any **css** file or **scss** will apply last value of that  styles

**EXAMPLE**

```
  .CLASS {
     font-size : 20px;
    }

 .CLASS {
     font-size : 10px;
  }
```

So it will encounter font-size : 10px;

Comment: Using `!important` is highly discouraged!!

Comment: Hey , @dako , it worked , I added the css to the styles.scss and it worked , Thanks man . But what's the reason behind it ? Why does it not work in Component level css ?

Comment: @AnandSrivastava please check updated answer

Comment: Thank you @DakoPatel , Learnt something new today